# How to develop a hierarchical model to see the heterogeneity in mean of a specific variable using glmer?

Tags: r, modeling, hierarchical

I am using the following model in R:

```r
glmer(y ~ x + z + (1|id), weights = specification, family = binomial, data = data)
```

which:

```r
y ~ binomial(y, specification)
Logit(y) = intercept + a*x + b*z
```

a and b are coefficients for x and z variables.

```
a|a0+a1 = a0 + a1*I
```

One of the variables (here x) depends on other variable (here I), so I need a hierarchical model to see the heterogeneity in mean of the x.

I would appreciate it if anyone could help me with this problem?
Sorry if the question does not look professional! This is one of my first experiences.

Comment: As your question seems to be more about the methodological principles underlying GLMMs rather than conding per se, you should ask your question on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) instead. Also, consult [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: is `I` an indicator variable?

Comment: @BenBolker Thank you very much for your reply! Actually, in my origin model the I variable is daily number of COVID cases and x variable is also a continuous variable.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not perfectly sure I understand the question, but: if `Logit(y) = intercept + a*x + b*z` and `a  = a0 + a1*I`, then it would seem that

```
Logit(y) = intercept + (a0+a1*I)*x + b*z
```

This looks like a straightforward interaction model:

```r
glmer(y ~ 1 + x + x:I + z + (1|id), ...)
```

to make it more explicit, this could also be written as

```r
glmer(y ~ 1 + x + I(x*I) + z + (1|id), ...)
```

(although the use of `I` as a predictor variable and in the `I()` function is a little bit confusing at first glance ...)